# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I had implemented `UITableView` with custom cell.It works fine.

Tableviewcell have 3 textfields in every cell.

I try to access all cell on submit button.

But app is crash due to access non-visible cell.

How can I got all cell's all 3 textfield values even they are not visible.

Thank you,

Comment: At what point are you trying to access the cell? Are you sure it has already loaded? Are you sure section 4 is correct? Could you have meant row 4?

Comment: @RichmondWatkins, Thanks a lot for your answer. yes I am sure for IndexPath. I am accessing cell in IBAction method

Comment: @RichmondWatkins, may be CellForRowIndex is not called for section 4 because I do not scroll to section 4. is it so?

Comment: but you said that cell is visible for you? cellForRowAtIndexPath will return nil if cell not visible

Comment: yes, when it is visible then crash due to txt assign with nil & when not visible then crash due to not assign memory,right?

if memory not assign because scroll is not done then how to solve that?

Comment: > when it is visible then crash due to txt assign with nil - I am lost with this comment. Can you specify please, at what lines you got crash

Comment: @ShadowOf, for got about " txt assign", just thought about when cell not visible then crash due to not assign memory & accessing this will cause nil, then how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method will return nil if cell not visible. You should check for this, and perform only data source changes if so:

```
if let cell_note = self.tbl.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 4)) as? NotesCell
{
    // do something with your data source
    // do something with cell_note that already loaded on screen
}
else
{
    // do something with your data source
    // your cell didn't loaded yet
    // you should only prepare fresh information in your data source for delegate method tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) 
}
```

Note that if you have same data source changes for both cases (as usual in fact), you need move them out of this check

Comment: but it is also release the cell if I scroll up then First section of cell is deallocated.

I want to make request with the change of first section of first cell. how can I do that?

Comment: @user2526811 change your mind about how `UITableView` work. Usually you should not manage cells on screen, they are managed by `UITableView` automatically. This results big benefits in performance and memory management (think about thousands row and sections). Usually, the only two things you should care about - 1) is to keep your data source updated 2) find and simply refresh visible cells when data source changes

Comment: So, there is no way to access that cell?

Comment: So what is solution for this?

Comment: @user2526811 solution is perform right architecture. As I see from edited question, you trying to keep data in views (in cells), but this is completely wrong design, this is anti-MVC-pattern. You should update data source immediately after receive data in your `UITextField`'s; and when you will need this data later, you should grab it from data source, not from cell!